# How can you set webform to create a new relationship rather than update an expired relationship when the relationship type and person is the same?

Tags: webform-civicrm, relationships

Using webform to create relationships in CiviCRM. If contact 1 already has a existing relationship of the correct type to contact 2 even if it is expired it will update that relationship.

We would like to track when they had a relationship to X.
Is there a way we can enter the relationship information through a webform and have it create a new relationship with X rather than updating their previous relationship to X?

We are using Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.7 (also happening on 4.6.25) webform_civicrm 7.x-4.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved in https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/75

This PR provides a field on the Additional options tab under CiviCRM on your webform so you can set it on a per webform basis. If you check the box then if there is an existing relationship of the same type with the other contact then it will create a new relationship record with the new start date rather than updating the old one.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was previously a [discussion about this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2511208) on the module's issue tracker. And I agree in principle that it would be good to allow this. Although there may be some disagreement from anyone who favors the current behavior.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps there is a way to allow people to choose their preferred behaviour depending on the function of their form. Would it be better to continue thinking about this back on the other discussion?